# compress eps image size in illustartor

Tags: image-processing, compression, adobe-illustrator

I have a very High resolution image in illustrator, which leads to a very heavy eps file size, I'm asking for a batch tool or a script to compress the eps image , in other words reduce its resolution without affecting the width and height of the image.I don't want to export the image as a separated Jpg file

Comment: I want my eps to be with the same extension .eps not eps.gz , I have to use it directly not the compressed version.

Comment: I mean I want to compress only the image encoded in eps format, in other words I want to reduce its quality or resolution by this way the eps file size will be reduced.

Answer (score 3):

Illustrator actually has a pretty good EPS algorithm; another program might make it a little smaller, but not by much.  I don't think EPS has an internal compression algorithm (like we're used to lossy JPG or lossless LZW TIFF)... it's not that kind of format.

That said, there are a few things you can do, to make an EPS file smaller:

- convert all fonts to outlines and/or uncheck "Embed Fonts" in save dialog
- simplify path detail ( **Object >> Path >> Simplify** )
- Keep fancy bitmap effects (like shadows and transparency) to a minimum.  If you do use these, make sure your image dimensions match what you're using the image for: e.g. if you're designing a postage stamp, your image should not be 8.5 x 11, which would trigger full res effects... essentially this makes your nice vector image into a raster trojan horse.
- Don't save an image preview with the image.